# Rooms are not removed after everyone leaves

Tags: node.js, socket.io

As far i read from the doc
that `Rooms are left automatically upon disconnection` and they are `automatically removed when everyone leaves`. But this is not the case of my actual code:

```
io.on('connection', function(socket) {


  socket.join(MainRoom);
  io.sockets.adapter.rooms[socket.id].owner = socket.username;

   //send the list of available rooms on connection
    socket.to(MainRoom).emit('updateList',io.sockets.adapter.rooms);

    socket.on('getUpdateList',function()  {
        io.to(MainRoom).emit('updateList',io.sockets.adapter.rooms);
    });

    socket.on('msg', function(msg) {
        io.to(MainRoom).emit('msgFront',msg);
      });



    socket.on('disconnect', function() {
        console.log('leaving '+socket.id);
        io.to(MainRoom).emit('updateList',io.sockets.adapter.rooms);


      });

});
```

Notice that I'm using a MainRoom where all client are forced to join it just to make sure that everyone can talk to each other.

By default `Each Socket in Socket.IO is identified by a random, unguessable, unique identifier Socket#id. For your convenience, each socket automatically joins a room identified by this id.`

My problem is that after closing/refreshing the browser tab, all previously joined rooms are still there, and the number of rooms is incremented(on connection the socket join new rooms automatically..)

Anyone can explain this behavior ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved:**

The problem is that i extended the rooms object bu adding owner attribute :

```
  io.sockets.adapter.rooms[socket.id].owner = socket.username;
```

So that the extended room can't be removed. the solution that i found is to store owner attribute outside within an associative array, that's it.